# Need help setting up application.properties / hibernate and spring classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm sure I'm missing something important, but I cannot seem to get a simple hibernate and spring program up and running.

My main class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

    }
}
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

DaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {


        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Query<Customer> theQuery = session.createQuery("FROM CUSTOMER", Customer.class);

        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return customers;

    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;


    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model){

        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDao.getCustomers();

        model.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";

    }
}
```

My Hibernate config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My print trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.6/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.3.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-04-09 18:08:06.824  INFO 4453 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 4453 (/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes started by ronald in /Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial)
2017-04-09 18:08:06.828  INFO 4453 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-09 18:08:07.086  INFO 4453 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1dd92fe2: startup date [Sun Apr 09 18:08:07 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-09 18:08:08.443  INFO 4453 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-09 18:08:08.515  INFO 4453 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-09 18:08:08.577  INFO 4453 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d4b47eda] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-09 18:08:09.042  INFO 4453 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-09 18:08:09.061  INFO 4453 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-09 18:08:09.063  INFO 4453 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-04-09 18:08:09.197  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-09 18:08:09.197  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2116 ms
2017-04-09 18:08:09.416  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-09 18:08:09.422  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-09 18:08:09.422  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-09 18:08:09.423  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-09 18:08:09.423  INFO 4453 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-09 18:08:09.502  WARN 4453 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
2017-04-09 18:08:09.515  INFO 4453 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-04-09 18:08:09.527 ERROR 4453 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:143) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:137) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1647) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:46) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:41) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post my print trace, its up there now

Comment: Where is your spring config xml file (if any)?

Comment: I don't have one, that may explain what I'm doing wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

You did not configure the `sessionFactory` bean, you need to add the below `Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyProjectDBConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Also, you can provide the hibernate specific properties into your `application.properties` itself as shown below (so, you don't need Hibernate config xml):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: The properties will only work if you use JPA with an `Entitymanager` those won't work for the manually setup session factory.

Answer (score 0):

According to your print stack, the error come from that line :

```
HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

It doesn't find your hibernate properties.
Use `@PropertySource("classpath:[path to your property file]")`

Comment: That isn't an error it is an informational message.